# Using FileResult in dotnet MAUI to populate DataTemplate in View

Tags: xaml, .net-core, maui

I am upgrading a Xamarin forms app to Dotnet MAUI. I have a control that allows the user to pick one or more files from the device, saves the details in an IEnumerable<FileResult> and displays the list in a view. In the Xamarin version, the relevant XAML looks like this:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="AttachmentList" ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttachment}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="essentials:FileResult" >
           <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Frame Style="{StaticResource AttachmentBubble}">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Image Source="{Binding FullPath}" HeightRequest="80" />
                       <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

MAUI doesn't recognise the datatype "essentials:FileResult" (fair enough as there is no longer an Essentials namespace in MAUI). FileResult is in the Microsoft.Maui.Storage namespace.

I've tried replacing the DataTemplate entry with:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="FileResult" >
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="storage:FileResult" >
```

but neither work, giving me an error that the type FileResult (or storage:FileResult) does not exist.

What is the MAUI equivalent that I need to make this work?

Comment: Have you declared either of those namespaces in you XAML?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with:   xmlns:storage="clr-namespage:Microsoft.Maui.Storage"

Comment: `DataType` is a XAML helper and should not effect the runtime behavior of the app.  Have you tried just removing that?

Comment: Yes I have, but then the FullPath and Filename propeties in the collection aren't recognised. The DataType needs to be there because the binding to the collection view is a property of the view model (AttachmentList) and the items it displays are of type FileResult.

Comment: This should not be an issue.  `DataType` is only a XAML helper.  It is not required.  I never use it.

Comment: @Jason appreciate your help. Have you actually used FileResult in a MAUI project and got it working?

Comment: I just did a test with your XAML and it worked fine

Comment: Can you share the project you used in the test somewhere? I'm obviously missing something in my project that prevents FileResult from being recognised in the XAML.

Comment: initially I just removed the `DataType`, as I suggested several times.  But I also was able to get it to work with it, by correcting the `xmlns`.  See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `FileResult` is in a different assembly than your page, you have to specify the namespace and the assembly

```
xmlns:storage="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Storage;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials"
```

Comment: Thanks. So the bit I was missing was the ;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials Not sure why it is that since Microsoft.Maui.Essentials no longer exists according to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-RC1. For reference, the <DataTemplate x:DataType="storage:FileResult"> line is required in the XAML - the project will not build without it as it errors complaining that the binding properties FullPath and FileName in StackLayout inside the DataTemplate are not found on the viewmodel.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're completely wrong about `DataType` being necessary.  If you have **other occurences** of that in the XAML then you may need one in the `DataTemplate` otherwise the template will inherit the parent's value, which will break.  But there is no general requirement to use them.  And that link does not say anything about the actual assembly structure - if you use the Assembly Browser there is clearly still a **lot of code** in that assembly, even if the namespaces have been updated.